# Validate laravel

Tags: laravel-7

tengo la siguiente validación y me esta dando problemas (no estoy seguro que sea eso), puse el primer dd campo por campo para ir verificando y los muestra todos, no obstante cuando quiero usar solamente en segundo dd con la data validada no muestra absolutamente nada, ni siquiera lo retorna en pantalla.
Espero que se entienda lo que quiero explicar, básicamente no se ejecuta nada del resto del código después del $request->validate()[image: fui mostrando campo por campo]

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validacion
    dd($request->validate(['categoria_id' => 'required']));
    $data = $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'categoria_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'imagen_principal' => 'required|image|max:1000',
        'direccion' => 'required',
        'partido' => 'required',
        'lat' => 'required',
        'lng' => 'required',
        'telefono' => 'required|numeric',
        'descripcion' => 'required|min:50',
        'apertura' =>'date_format:H:i',
        'cierre' => 'date_format:H:i|after:apertura',
        'uuid' => 'required|uuid',
    ]);
    dd($data['nombre']);
    //guardar la imagen
    $ruta_imagen = $request['imagen_principal']->store('principales', 'public');

    //resize
    $img = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$ruta_imagen}"))->fit(800, 600);
    $img->save();
    
    $establecimiento = new Establecimiento($data);
    $establecimiento->imagen_principal = $ruta_imagen;
    $establecimiento->user_id = auth()->id;
    $establecimiento->save();
    

    dd('desde store');
}
```

Comment: Por que le método `dd` hace un volcado de la data y detiene la ejecución del script, por lo tanto tu código parará en el `$request->validate` y de ahi en mas no seguirá, ya que significa `dump and die`

Comment: U otra cosa... Si no se ejecuta nada del resto del código después del $request->validate(), debe ser porque el request no pasa la validación. > "Si pasan las reglas de validación, su código seguirá ejecutándose normalmente; sin embargo, si la validación falla, se lanzará una excepción y la respuesta de error adecuada se enviará automáticamente al usuario. En el caso de una solicitud HTTP tradicional, se generará una respuesta de redireccionamiento, mientras que se enviará una respuesta JSON para las solicitudes AJAX."

Comment: Aprovechando que te veo por aqui @porloscerrosΨ, en el chat alguien ocupa apoyo de *Laravel* igual y te interesa darte una vuelta por allá :)

Comment: Claro los dd los fui escribiendo para probar hasta donde llegaba el código, estuve probando campo por campo y todos parecen correctos, tampoco parece estar mal sintácticamente una de las validaciones, no logro hacer que se ejecute nada después del $request->validate(), si me pueden decir como podría seguir buscando el error se los agradecería.

Comment: Revisa que te responde la petición

Comment: Te refieres a campo por campo o ya existe un método para revisarla? Disculpa no quiero que parezca que quiero la solución en bandeja solo que soy nuevo con el frame y estoy hace 3 días sin poder avanzar.

Comment: En el navegador, abre las herramientas de desarrollador y ve a la pestaña red (o network). Ahí selecciona la petición y ve la respuesta

Comment: https://support.google.com/campaignmanager/answer/2828688?hl=es